# Is there a way to build a Bada App using an existing HTML5/jQuery/CSS3 webapp?

Tags: jquery, web-applications, html, sdk, bada

I want to avoid having to rewrite the entire app. I know that for mobile phones, there's phone gap, and I'm wondering if there's a method or service similar for Bada.

For reference / mobile phones:
http://www.phonegap.com/

Answer (score 1):

you can use the normal bada IDE and then make a web application, there you have a already app with a browser where you can run html etc. local in your app

Comment: bada web application uses it's own rendering system, I couldn't use my web skills (for example jquery) on bada platform